# Alter table command on complex data type column ( Nested struct ) not working in spark thrift server

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hive-metastore, spark-thriftserver

I am trying to run an alter table command using beeline connecting to sparkt thrift server which is configured to use remote hive metastore. I am getting the following error.

Table is created using below command:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_schema`.`nested_test_pq` (`key1` ARRAY<STRUCT<`a`: STRING, `b`: STRING, `c`: STRING>>) USING parquet
```

Alter table command I am trying

```
alter table test_schema.nested_test_pq change key1  key1 type array<struct<a:string,b:string,c:string,d:string>>;
```

Error I am getting is

`alter table test_schema.nested_test_pq change key1  key1 array<struct<a:string,b:string,c:string,d:string>>;             Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN is not supported for  changing column 'key1' with type 'ArrayType(StructType(StructField(a,StringType,true), StructField(b,StringType,true), StructField(c,StringType,true)),true)' to  'key1' with type 'ArrayType(StructType(StructField(a,StringType,true), StructField(b,StringType,true), StructField(c,StringType,true), StructField(d,StringType,t rue)),true)'                                                                                                                                                      at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServerErrors$.runningQueryError(HiveThriftServerErrors.scala:43)`

I already tried the configuration `hive.metastore.disallow.invalid.col.type.changes` to `true` but no luck.

Spark version - 3.2.1

Hive metastore version - 3.0.0

Hadoop version - 3.2.0

Comment: shouldn't you change `hive.metastore.disallow.invalid.col.type.changes` to `false` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `add` a single nested column instead of `change` entire struct.

`spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE {db}.{table} ADD COLUMNS (key1.d string AFTER key1.c)")`